# Laravel Eloquent Relationships latest

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am creating a quote. My tables look something like this:

```
quote:
    PK:id
    name
    FK:client_id
    FK:user_id
    created_at
quoteSkus:
    PK:id
    FK:quote_id
    FK:sku_id
    price
sku:
    PK:id
    name
    created_at
```

My relationships look like this:

**Quote.php**

```
public function skus(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Http\Models\Quotesku','quote_id','id');
}
public function client(){
    return $this->hasOne('\App\Http\Models\Client', 'id','client_id');
}
public function contact(){
    return $this->hasOne('\App\Http\Models\Contact', 'id','contact_id');
}
```

**QuotaSkus.php**

```
public function sku(){
    return $this->hasOne("\App\Http\Models\Sku","id","sku_id");
}
public function quote(){
    return $this->hasOne("\App\Http\Models\Quote","id","quote_id");
}
```

**sku.php**

```
public function lastUsage(){
    return $this->hasOne('\App\Http\Models\Quotesku','sku_id','id');
}
```

I want to get the price that was set for this `sku` in this clients last quote.

This query will give me just that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `skus` as s 
RIGHT JOIN quoteskus as qs on qs.sku_id = s.id
RIGHT JOIN quotes as q on q.id = qs.quote_id
where s.id = 236
AND q.client_id = 2
order by q.created_at DESC
```

Is it possible to set this up with eloquent relationships?
So I will be able to

```
$sku = new Sku();
$sku->find(1);
$sku->lastUsage->price;
```

**or**

```
$sku->lastUsage(client_id)->price;
```

Sorry for the code dump, I tried to sum it up as much as I could.

Any advice would help. Thank you :)

Comment: Models are usually placed in app directory, and app\http directory generally used for controllers and middlewares. Are you sure that your models are placed in app\http\models?

Comment: Have you try adding `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` to your `lastUsage*()` method?

Comment: @NIKHILNEDIYODATH Yes, This is my first Laravel project so i wasn't sure where to place the model files. This setup works, it just isn't elegant.

Comment: @i-- The table `quotesku` doesn't have a `created_at` column. I don't want to save this data as it is already saved in the `quote` table.

Comment: @NIKHILNEDIYODATH,  no :|

Comment: @NIKHILNEDIYODATH, the rest of my relations work great though.

Comment: "You have to make models by using php artisan command" @NIKHILNEDIYODATH No, you don't **have** to. Should you? Probably, but there is nothing wrong with copying an existing model to another, renaming class and file and using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here should be what you want:

```
public function lastUsageByClient($client_id) {
    return $this->join('quoteSkus', 'sku.id', '=', 'quoteSkus.sku_id')
        ->join('quote', 'quote.id', '=', 'quoteSkus.quote_id')
        ->select('sku.*', 'quoteSkus.price')
        ->where('quote.client_id', $client_id)
        ->orderBy('quote.created_at', 'desc')
        ->first();
}
```

Not pretty, but should work.

**EDIT:**

```
public function lastUsage() {
    return $this->hasOne('\App\Http\Models\Quotesku','sku_id','id')
        ->join('quote', 'quote.id', 'quoteSkus.quote_id')
        ->orderBy('quote.created_at', 'desc');
}
```

You might want to specify which columns to pull here as well.

Comment: This is not using `Eloquent Relationships`. Why is this any better then just running the query that I posted?

Comment: I actually try staying away from using columns other than foreign keys on pivot tables, which eliminates the need of creating model for a pivot table and makes it easier to write code. I have tweaked the code slightly to make it use `hasOne()`.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid "non-elegant" code if you need filtering by fields from both `quote` & `sku` tables.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right, this has to be messy. In your edit you use the `hasOne` which it exactly what I wanted, so thank you for that! I don't know if this solution is better or worse than the query I had in, but the code looks cleaner so I am happy :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following

```
$sku = Sku::find(1);
$quotesku = $sku->lastUsage->price;
```

And **sku.php**

```
public function lastUsage(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Http\Models\Quotesku','sku_id','id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
}
```

Comment: This returns the price of the first use and not the last use. Also it does not give me the option to filter by client.

Comment: The parameter passing to find is the id of sku. That is, it will return sku instance with id 1, and it is stored in $sku. lastusage is a hasone relationship that means there is only one quotesku corresponding to one sku. Then where you have to filter?

Comment: `lastuseage` is set to `hasOne` because i only want to get 1 back, the leatest one based on its quota. I dont have any filtering. my question is can it be done using `Eloquent Relationships`. I have already accomplished this using the query in the original post.

Comment: @DvirLevy as far as I understand - you can't filter relationship (like you want by client there) because it can be used interchangeably as property and as method.